# Qual a melhor maneira de capturar o redimensionamento da tela em tempo real?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Existe uma maneira melhor para pegar em tempo real o redimensionamento da tela?

Preciso saber se é mobile ou desktop, na medida que eu redimensione a tela, porque da forma que está não é 100% eficaz... (já tentei com `document.documentElement.clientWidth` e `document.body.clientWidth`), mas algumas vezes ele pára de funcionar.

O `media queries de CSS` funciona bem para esconder elementos e ajustar, mas ele não me ajuda para desabilitar métodos.

Eu preciso pegar uma variável no controller do angularjs para poder desabilitar alguns métodos na versão mobile, como este exemplo que faz o menu mobile parar de funcionar porque dá conflito com a versão do menu mobile: `click-outside="outSideMenuExplorer()"` a ideia é fazer isso não existir na versão mobile, exemplo:

`click-outside="(!is_mobile) ? outSideMenuExplorer() : null"`

```
$scope.is_mobile = false;

var size_mob = Boolean(window.innerWidth < 768 && window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight);  

window.onresize = function() {
  $scope.is_mobile = size_mob;
}
```

Comment: Você pode usar essa lib aqui [https://github.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector](https://github.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector).

Comment: Dizes _"mas algumas vezes ele pára de funcionar"_ - funcionaria melhor se chamasses `is_mobile()` cada vez que precises? tendo `const is_mobile = ()=> Boolean(window.innerWidth < 768 && window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight);`podes chamar sempre que necessário...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Existe uma maneira melhor para pegar em tempo real o redimensionamento da tela?

O evento [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) é o único método em tempo real para capturar o ajuste após o redimensionamento da janela.

> Preciso saber se é mobile ou desktop, na medida que eu redimensione a tela, porque da forma que está não é 100% eficaz...

Não existe uma API ou biblioteca com eficacia de 100% para determinar se é um acesso mobile/desktop.

Tanto usando o back-end como front-end a maioria dos métodos e bibliotecas usa a cadeia fornecida pelo **"user-agent"** para "tentar" filtrar. Esta cadeia pode ser facilmente forjada por bots ou plugins para parecer algo diferente do que é (são).

Talvez uma lógica para testar recursos ajude a encontrar um pouco mais de consistência.

- **tentar criar um `TouchEvent`**
- **verificar a propriedade `ontouchstart`**
- **verificar o `mediaQueryList`**

`TouchEvent` irá ser criado em qualquer dispositivo que suporte "touch" inclusive monitores "touch-screen" ... caso não suporte um `DOM Exception` será lançado.

As demais consultas (`ontouchstart` e `mediaQueryList`) também devem lançar algum tipo de erro em caso de falha. Tudo isso em um bloco `try/catch` deve ser o suficiente ... no caso de um erro ou exceção, podes tentar consultar a cadeia fornecida pelo **"user-agent"**.

Vale ressaltar que tanto `navigator.userAgent` quanto o cabeçalho **"user-agent:"** serão preteridos em breve em favor da nova especificação [Clients Hint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Client_hints) proposta pelo Google e apoiada pelos principais fornecedores (consulte: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5704553745874944)

```js
var container = document.getElementById('box');

/**
 * Is mobile?
 * @see original referrer {@link http://mobiledetect.com} (site down)
 * @return { Boolean }
 */
function isMobile() {
    var dc = document,
        wd = window;
    // get browser "User-Agent" or vendor ... see "opera" property in `window`
    var wua = (wd.navigator.userAgent || wd.navigator.vendor || wd.opera || '');
    try {
        /**
         * Creating a touch event ... in modern browsers with touch screens or emulators (but not mobile) does not cause errors.
         * Otherwise, it will create a `DOMException` instance
         */
        dc.createEvent("TouchEvent");

        // check touchStart event
        (('ontouchstart' in wd) || ('ontouchstart' in dc.documentElement) || wd.DocumentTouch && wd.document instanceof DocumentTouch || wd.navigator.maxTouchPoints || wd.navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) ? void(0) : new Error('failed check "ontouchstart" event');

        // check `mediaQueryList` ... pass as modern browsers
        var mQ = wd.matchMedia && matchMedia("(pointer: coarse)");
        // if no have, throw error to use "User-Agent" sniffing test
        if ( !mQ || mQ.media !== "(pointer: coarse)" || !mQ.matches ) {
            throw new Error('failed test `mediaQueryList`');
        }

        // if there are no failures the possibility of the device being mobile is great (but not guaranteed)
        return true;
    } catch(ex) {
        // fall back to User-Agent sniffing
        return /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(wua) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(wua.substr(0,4));
    }
};

window.onresize = function() {
    container.innerHTML = isMobile() ? 'Mobile' : 'Desktop';
};
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Os créditos da [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) usada aqui vão para o antigo site http://mobiledetect.com que já não está mais online más, ainda serve bem para entender seu funcionamento.

---

Diferentes frameworks de `CSS` usam consultas de media para determinar seus **"break-points"** ... usá-los para mostrar ou ocultar ou buscar as medidas no objeto `window` talvez não sejam o melhor caminho pois muitos dispositivos basicos/intermediários e tops de linha (smartphones/tablets) oferecem uma alta resolução.

Comment: Acho que funcionou bem o seu de cima para ir para o modo responsivo, mas ainda tenho o problema do tamanho da tela que não funcionou perfeito: `$scope.is_mobile = (isMobile() && window.innerWidth < 768);`. Mas valeu pelo esforço...

Comment: Ainda preciso considerar uma tela menor... sem precisar dar refresh.

Comment: Estava pensando em algo do tipo: `window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches`

Comment: Se realmente é importante podes considerar complementar: `var mQ = wd.matchMedia && matchMedia("(pointer: coarse)") && wd.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");`. Não testei mas talvez sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que talvez possa resolver isso usando apenas CSS:

```
   .state-indicator {
     display: none;
   }

@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    [data-type="small-desktop"]{display: block}
}

/* tablet */
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    [data-type="tablet"]{display: block}
}

/* mobile phone */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    [data-type="mobile"]{display: block }
}
```

**Javascript:**

**Resposta na HTML:**

```
<div data-type="desktop" click-outside="outSideMenuExplorerDesktop()" class="state-indicator"></div>
<div data-type="mobile" click-outside="outSideMenuExplorerMobile()" class="state-indicator"></div>
<div data-type="tablet" click-outside="outSideMenuExplorerTablet()" class="state-indicator"></div>
<div data-type="small-desktop" click-outside="outSideMenuExplorerSmallDesktop()" class="state-indicator"></div>
```

Isso me ajudou a chegar numa fórmula:

[Fonte da referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688393/detect-dynamic-media-queries-with-javascript)